# gridelements appearance (images) in multilingual pages

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

I put two different images into the gridelements appearances of the standard language and the foreign language.
The images references are stored in the tables "sys-file" and "sys-file-reference". The image of the foreign language is stored with the uid of the translated CE instead with the uid of the standard CE AND the correct data in the field sys-language-uid?

So using an image e.g. for different backgrounds in the two languages is not possible, is it?

Comment: For my understanding: You have two languages and in each language you have a gridelement and you try to define different images in those gridelements but the translated CE still shows the image of the original gridelement even if you upload an other image in the translated CE?

Comment: Yes!
For each language one own image. I wrote a viewhelper to read sys-file and sys-file-reference to get the name of the images but I don't find a way to pick up the one of the translated gridelement which has an own UID with zero in the table field sys-language-uid.